# Azure Resource Group Stuck in "Moving Resources"

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group

I was doing some cleanup moving some Azure Cloud Services to a newly created Resource group with the following command

```
Find-AzureRmResource -ResourceNameContains "oldresourcename" |
Move-AzureRmResource -DestinationResourceGroupName "newresourcegroup" -Verbose
```

Everything was going fine, but the last one I ran seems to be taking a very long time. It is a simple CS with one worker role and one web role and small size.

The command has been in a not completed state for over an hour, and out on the Portal, both resource groups have "Moving Resources" in purple at the top of the page. I am going to wait until tomorrow to see if it still persists, but it should not be taking this long.

Is there a way to cancel or halt this operation? The concern is that both Resource Groups are locked till this process is complete, which will be an issue moving forward.

Comment: Have you been able to fix this. I'm also facing the same problem.

Comment: I am also facing this issue. Was anyone able to get this resolved.

Comment: @KeremDemirer, can you please tell us what happened with this?

Comment: @AmanSharma, can you please tell us what happened with this? Thanks!

Comment: @nmit026 I waited for 4-6 hours and the job failed and I was able to proceed agead next day.

Comment: I was using the portal, not the command line, suspect this is why it failed: "The destination subscription must be registered for the resource provider of the resource being moved. If not, you will receive an error stating that the subscription is not registered for a resource type. You might encounter this problem when moving a resource to a new subscription, but that subscription has never been used with that resource type." Source: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-move-resources/#checklist-before-moving-resources

Comment: @nmit026 Mine also, error gone after a while.

Comment: Having the same problem with the Portal at the moment as well. I've moving a key value at the moment and it's taking quite a long time.

Comment: I left it running all night and the service moved during that period.

Comment: wouldn't hurt to have a button to cancel the operation or something... I currently can't perform any operation in both the source and destination resource-group, which is very annoying

Comment: Sometimes it's just a problem with Microsoft. I'd the same problem and I opened a ticket. They executed a script and 15 minutes

Answer (score 4):

From my experience the move will eventually time out if there's an issue. I had a similar issue moving a web app and the SSL cert caused the move to fail, but it took a couple of hours for it to fail.

More information from Microsoft on what is able to move:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources

Comment: my resource appears to be on the target resource group although i am still receiving this error message.

Comment: how long is this time out? my resource is keep being updated since yesterday.

Comment: @Emil the timeout is 4 hours - i'm looking for how i can manually - stop/clear the locks because the resources all moved already